# SSIS - Referecing Env variables from multiple folders

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I want to know if it possible to reference environment variables from multiple folders ?

Example below, I have 3 folders. All variables related to Server are stored in ServerEnv folder. So that I can reference any server related variables without need to recreate them in separate folders. But the problem I facing now is SSIS only allowed me to choose ENV variables from 1 folder only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: SSIS would not allow you to map to multiple Environment variables. If you do need to make the process more easier, try to do it via T-SQL procedures provided in the SSISDB, setting up of environment folder, mapping etc..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Do you have documentation for this ? What is the best practice for this. My goal is to develop with least administration effort.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to do this myself. You can look into this link that provides a very good understanding of how to do automation - https://www.hansmichiels.com/2016/11/04/how-to-automate-your-ssis-package-deployment-and-configuration-ssis-series/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to reference environment variables from multiple folders.

You can either

1. Put all the packages in one folder with proper naming conventions to distinguish them. In this way, you should be able to refer to the same environment variable.
2. If you would like to use different folders for different projects, you can script the variables. Please find additional info at:http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/135173/

Hope that helps.

Cheers
Nithin